# Can I delete 'there' in the sentence 'The Customs Officers asked the man how much perfume there was in his case'?

Tags: word-usage

Can I delete 'there' in the sentence 
 ***The Customs Officers asked the man how much perfume there was in his case?***

Comment: No. And, I would prefer `was there` rather than `there was`.

Comment: @SandeepKumar Are `was there` and `there was` right?

Comment: @SandeepKumar Both your claims are wrong: "there was" is much better than "was there" and the sentence remains grammatical when "there" is removed.

Comment: @TypeIA Among `was there`, `there was` and `was`, which is the best one?

Comment: @TypeIA Well, I agree with the part of dropping `there`.  But, I would still prefer `was there` and I could be wrong in doing so.

Comment: @Y.zeng, What are you trying to achieve by dropping `there`?

Comment: @SandeepKumar I always drop `there`, but today I see a sentence including `there`, so I want to know if `there` could be dropped and which is the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypelA is absolutely correct. You can remove 'there' and maintain the sense and here suggestion for 'there was' is better English. This implies now. 'was there' implies before.

Answer (score 0):

*There was* and *there were* are perfectly idiomatic English when referring to a quantity or number of something that exists in a place.

"I looked to see how much milk there was in the bottle."

"The school inspector asked how many children there were in the class."